# problema con notifiaciones

Tags: java, android, android-studio

la notificación funciona bien, pero al pulsar la, me crea otra activiti en vez de abrir la que ya está en memoria, esto ocasiona que el audio siga reproduciendo, pero la nueva activitie no es capaz de interactuar con ese audio (digamos que tengo MainActivitie y al abrir la notificación con la app en segundo plano me crea otro MainActivitie). me gustiaria que al pulsar la notificación, o se vuelva a abrir la activitie que hay en memoria , otra opción seria finalizar la app, las dos opciones son validas pero no se llebarlas a cabo. 
Mi codigo:

```
package com.david.animefm2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.CollationElementIterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

import static android.R.drawable.ic_media_play;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList radios;
    private RadioAdapter adapter;
    private ListView lvRadios;
    private String url ="";
    private String txt = "";
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    private AdView mAdView;

    TextView texto;
    ImageView cover;

    int ns = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        texto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.etRadio);
        cover = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cover);

        //config
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9173335460606469/5989305154");
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdLoaded");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdFailedToLoad");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
                // covers the screen.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdOpened");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdLeftApplication");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
                // to the app after tapping on an ad.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdClosed");
            }
        });

        final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.start);
        //variables
        radios = new ArrayList<radio>();
        rellenarArrayList();
        adapter = new RadioAdapter(this, radios);
        lvRadios = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRadeo);
        lvRadios.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Lista
        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRadeo);
        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                SetUrl(i);
            }
        });


        //BOTON FLOTANTE

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    //metodo de pausa
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                } else {
                    BotonReproducir();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Nombre y icono
    private void rellenarArrayList() {
        radios.add(new radio("Radio Vocaloid", R.drawable.radiovocaloid)); //0
        radios.add(new radio("Radio Anime", R.drawable.radioanime)); //1
        radios.add(new radio("Anime Layer", R.drawable.animelayer)); //2
        radios.add(new radio("Anime Radio SU", R.drawable.radioanimesu)); //3
        radios.add(new radio("Anime Nexus", R.drawable.animenexus)); //4
        radios.add(new radio("Ani-Station", R.drawable.anistation)); //5
        radios.add(new radio("Big B Radio - Jpop", R.drawable.bigbjpop)); //6
        radios.add(new radio("Big B Radio - Kpop", R.drawable.bigbkpop)); //7
        radios.add(new radio("Blue Anime Ivana", R.drawable.blueanimelvana)); //8
        radios.add(new radio("Extreme Anime Radio", R.drawable.extremeanimeradio)); //9
        radios.add(new radio("JRok Radio", R.drawable.jrockradio)); //10
        radios.add(new radio("Nyan Server Radio", R.drawable.nyanradio)); //11
        radios.add(new radio("Otaku's Dream", R.drawable.otakudream)); //12
        radios.add(new radio("JHero Radio", R.drawable.jhero)); //13
        radios.add(new radio("Radio Rakuen Peru", R.drawable.rakuenradio)); //14

    };
    //Urls
    private void seturl(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                url= "http://curiosity.shoutca.st:8019/stream"; //Radio Vocaloid
                txt = "Radio Vocaloid";
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.radiovocaloid);
                break;
            case 1:
                url="http://perseus.shoutca.st:9253/stream"; //Radio Anime
                txt = "Radio Anime";
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.radioanime);
                break;
            case 2:
                url="http://animelayer.ru:5190/play"; //Anime Layer
                txt = "Anime Layer";
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.animelayer);
                break;
            case 3:
                url="http://animeradio.su:8000"; //Radio Anime SU
                txt = "Radio Anime SU";
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.radioanimesu);
                break;
            case 4:
                url="http://radio.animenexus.net:8000/animenexus"; //Anime Nexus
                txt = "Anime Nexus";
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.animenexus);
                break;
            case 5:
                url="http://streaming.radionomy.com/Ani-Station"; //Ani-Station
                txt = "Ani-Station";
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.anistation);
                break;
            case 6:
                url="http://64.71.79.181:8024/;"; //BBig B Radio - Jpop
                txt = "Big B Radio - Jpop";
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.bigbjpop);
                break;
            case 7:
                url="http://64.71.79.181:8040/;"; //BBig B Radio - Kpop
                txt = "Big B Radio - Kpop";
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.bigbkpop);
                break;
            case 8:
                url="http://streaming.radionomy.com/BlueAnimeIvana"; //Blue Anime Ivana
                txt = "Blue Anime Ivana";
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.blueanimelvana);
                break;
            case 9:
                url="http://174.37.159.206:8052/stream"; //Extreme Anime Radio
                txt = "Extreme Anime Radio";
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.extremeanimeradio);
                break;
            case 10:
                url="http://40.117.236.216:8100/;"; //JRock Radio
                txt = "JRok Radio";
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.jrockradio);
                break;
            case 11:
                url="http://radio.nyan.pw/station/stream"; //Nyan Server Radio
                txt = "Nyan Server Radio";
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.nyanradio);
                break;
            case 12:
                url="http://199.15.251.230:8048"; //Otaku's Dream
                txt = "Otaku's Dream";
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.otakudream);
                break;
            case 13:
                url="http://stm31.srvstm.com:9566"; //JHero Radio
                txt = "JHero Radio";
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.jhero);
                break;
            //falta
            case 14:
                url="http://67.212.165.162:7018"; //Radio Rakuen Peru
                txt = "Radio Rakuen Peru";
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.rakuenradio);
                break;



        };

        texto.setText(txt);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), txt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        notificacion(R.drawable.rakuenradio, txt);
        BotonReproducir();
    }

    private void SetUrl(int i){
        if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
        }
        seturl(i);
    }

    private void BotonReproducir() {
        if (url != "") {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                //mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                    //Inicia reproducción.
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bufering...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    // Lanzo la notificacion creada en el paso anterior
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Select a rario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void notificacion (int icono, String radio){

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =(NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        //int icono = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, i, 0);

        mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(icono)
                .setContentTitle("Anime Fm 2")
                .setContentText("Reproduciendo "+radio+" en segundo plano")
                //.setVibrate(new long[] {100, 250, 100, 500})
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        if (mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mNotifyMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        } else {
            mNotifyMgr.cancel(1);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"7. onResume()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //nm.cancel(1);
        notificacion(R.drawable.rakuenradio, txt);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"8. onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //nm.cancel(1);
        notificacion(R.drawable.rakuenradio, txt);
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"9. onPause()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //nm.notify(1, notif);
        notificacion(R.drawable.rakuenradio, txt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta abriendo nuevamente MainActivity ya que tienes definido un `PendingIntent` que define abrir `MainActivity` desde `MainActivity`, podrías evitar configurar este `PendingIntent`:

```
 Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, i, 0);
```

**Si deseas abrir únicamente la aplicación, al dar click en la notificación**, define el `PendingIntent` con las siguientes Flags:

```
Intent iNormal = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, msgId | MASK_ACTION_OPEN, iNormal, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

y configuralo a tu Notificación:

```
 mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                ...
                ...
```

Comment: no consigo hacer lo que comentas, no hace nada al ejecutarlo

Comment: Agregué como podrías abrir solo tu aplicación sin abrirla nuevamente si es que esta esta activa.